# Image rendering on first load, shows its original height and width, not applying mentioned css for that

Tags: html, css

I need to make sure some images have a specific width applied (using *CSS* class) straight away when the browser begins render.

Currently, on networks with limited bandwidth, images show their original height and width, not applying defined *CSS* rules right away. Setting `max-height` and `width` did not help.

```css
.image-container{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Earth_poster_large.jpg' />
```

Comment: can you provide any working example like code-snippet or fiddle , this will help us to solve your real problem .

Comment: You have to use `class` as an HTML element's attribute, not `className`. →`<img src="image" class="image-container">`

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the width, just the max-width, so if the containing element is wider than the original image it will not change anything.
Try changing `max-width: 100%;` to `width: 100%;`

Comment: @arleight okay, I have added above-mentioned property still the same issue.

Comment: That's the only thing I can think of, with what you have shown. Please add more code to your question, so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is some solution to it.

We can make the importance low for that image while rendering so that, our initial css will not apply in faster rendering.

```
<img src="xyz.png" importance="low">
```

Second is, we are applying, the css class `display:none` for component, onloading.
Once our API is resolved and Loader is removed the style would be class `display:block`.

Make sure your `hideComponent` className should be in main.css.